# Error running Tomcat trying to connect to a Docker container

Tags: database, docker

Previously I kept getting the access denied error but at least it was trying to set a connection. Now this is all I get: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master). I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Use the name of container or the service name if you used docker compose instead of localhost for the mysql connection

Comment: @TarunLalwani right now my url is "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/equity_cth_********:latest". should I change it somehow?

Comment: How did you run the mysql docker container?

Comment: @AnthonyMofo - is that problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Docker containers run on a bridge network. Thus the Docker container's `localhost` does *not* point to the localhost of the Docker host inside which the container runs.

Find out the IP address of your Docker host:

```bash
ifconfig \
| grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" \
| grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
| awk '{ print $2 }' \
| cut -f2 -d: \
| head -n1
```

Or if you're on macOS, you can use `docker.for.mac.localhost` (or `docker.for.win.localhost` on Windows).